# Dacpac deployment to Azure via SSMS failed: Cannot alter the role db_owner

Tags: sql-server, azure-devops, dacpac

I am trying to use a dacpac file created using the Azure DevOps pipeline. I am trying to use the Upgrade data-tier Application option in SQL Server Management Studio 19.1.56.0.

This steps by step in Upgrade data-tier Application
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

When I am trying to finish it, I got an error
[image]

I tried to save the T-SQL script and comment out the lines and blocks that are responsible for deleting users, but it didn't work for some reason.

like:

```
/*
GO
PRINT N'Dropping Role Membership [db_owner] for [blala]...';


GO
EXECUTE sp_droprolemember @rolename = N'db_owner', @membername = N'blala';


GO
IF @@ERROR <> 0
   AND @@TRANCOUNT > 0
    BEGIN
        ROLLBACK;
    END

IF OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..#tmpErrors') IS NULL
    CREATE TABLE [#tmpErrors] (
        Error INT
    );

IF @@TRANCOUNT = 0
    BEGIN
        INSERT  INTO #tmpErrors (Error)
        VALUES                 (1);
        BEGIN TRANSACTION;
    END
*/
```

end etc...

Is there any way to fix this at the time of upgrade. Or dacpac file only needs to be recreated in Azure DevOps (and how)?

Answer (score 0):

The following are the steps I use to deploy SQL server using DevOps pipeline via DACPAC file for your reference.

1. Create a SQL Server DB project (SSTD) in VS and import my DB into the project. You can make changes to the DB in the project.

   Right click on the project -> Import ->Database
   [image]
2. Create a repo in Azure DevOps and push the changes.
   [image]
3. Build the project to get the DACPAC file in a pipeline.

```
trigger:
- none

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

variables:
  solution: '**/*.sln'
  buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'

steps:
- task: VSBuild@1
  inputs:
    solution: '$(solution)'
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'

- task: CopyFiles@2
  inputs:
    SourceFolder: '$(system.defaultworkingdirectory)'
    Contents: '**\bin\$(BuildConfiguration)\**'
    TargetFolder: '$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'

- task: PublishPipelineArtifact@1
  inputs:
    targetPath: '$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'
    artifact: 'drop'
    publishLocation: 'pipeline'
```

4. Create a classic release pipeline to deploy the DACPAC file to your target DB.

- Select the build pipeline above as an artifact.
- Deploy using [SQL Server database deploy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/sql-dacpac-deployment-on-machine-group-v0?view=azure-pipelines) task. (For Azure SQL, you can use [Azure SQL Database deployment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/targets/azure-sqldb?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) task. For Azure SQL Data Warehouse, you can use [Azure SQL Data Warehouse deployment](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-sql-dw.SQLDWDeployment) task.)
  [image]
- Ensure the user you use to login has enough permissions to make the changes you define in your SSTD project.

Comment: I don't know if this solution will work in my case. I don't have access to the database, I only use Azure DevOps pipeline capabilities to create the dacpac file.

I tried to add the `/p:ExcludePermissions=true` parameter to the Build solution `NameAP.sln` step to exclude adding permissions to dacpac, but it doesn't seem to work.

I've added a link to the screenshot.
https://ibb.co/pnXmpVH

Comment: It turns out that it is necessary to exclude the error at the moment of dacpac file creation.

`Error SQL72014: Framework Microsoft SqlClient Data Provider: Msg 15151, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Cannot alter the role 'db_owner', because it does not exist or you do not have permission.
Error SQL72045: Script execution error.  The executed script:
EXECUTE sp_droprolemember @rolename = N'db_owner', @membername = N'uidv0000@cw01';`